# Are there hybrid metaheuristic-solvers to solve combinatorial optimization problems?

Tags: linear-programming, solver, combinatorial-optimization, metaheuristics

I have a problem which is formulating a linear program. To solve large instances I implement a metaheuristic to solve my problem. In my problem, I have two objective functions.

With my linear program, I can minimize the second objective in polynomial time. So I test to solve the first objective function using metaheuristic and then take the result and make it a constraint in my linear program and solve the linear program to minimize the second objective. Is this method valid?

Comment: What is your first objective? If it's nonlinear, how can you use the solution to the first problem as a constraint in the 2nd problem, which is an LP?  it the first objective is linear, why don't use solve it with an LP solver?

Comment: both objectives are linear. I have implemented my linear program and solved it using the epsilon-constraint method under the Gurobi solver and that works well. Now, when I try to solve large instances, the solver takes a long time to solve the LP with only the objective function F1 whereas the solver can solve the LP to minimize F2 with the same constraints in a few seconds. So, I decide to solve my problem using metaheuristic to minimize F1 then make the result as constraint for the LP to minimize F2 (as it can be solved in polynomial time). that is my proposed framework.

Comment: Optimizing one objective, making its value a constraint and optimizing the second objective is a common approach to multiobjective problems (referred to as "preemptive priorities" or "lexicographic optimization"). Whether you consider your approach "valid" or not depends on how you feel about the possibility that the objective value you lock in for F1 might not actually be optimal (because the metaheuristic did not find an optimal solution).

Comment: @MAJIDmajid, I am not sure this might be the best way, but you can use some of the open-source libraries like [this](https://github.com/jMetal/jMetalPy) to solve MOOP by using metaheuristics (actually, you will need to translate your problem into the format that can be read by those solvers) to achieve a feasible solution. Then test this solution by your mathematical program to prove that this solution really is a feasible or not and how far from the optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you for this understandable explanation. As my first objective is optimized using metaheuristic, so objective 2 despite using an exact method the result will be a near-optimal solution because it depends on the result of the first step(optimizing F1) which is a near-optimal solution.